# Why do I have empty tokens in Java String.split(regex)?

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regular expression, I'm trying to use it to parse tokens separated by "(", ")" and blank space. This is my attempt:

```
String str = "(test (_bit1 _bit2 |bit3::&92;test#4|))";
String[] tokens = str.split("[\\s*[()]]"); 
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
  System.out.println(i + " : " + tokens[i]);
```

I expect the following output:

> 0 : test
>     1 : _bit1
>     2 : _bit2
>     3 : |bit3::&92;test#4|

However, there are two empty tokens appear in the actual output:

> 0 :
>     1 : test
>     2 :
>     3 : _bit1
>     4 : _bit2
>     5 : |bit3::&92;test#4|

I don't understand why I have two empty tokens in position 0 and 2. Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you.

===== Update ====

There was an answer of [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore) who deleted it. But I like the answer, so I copy it here for my own reference.

> Your regex, [\s*[()]], matches one whitespace character (\s) or one of
>   the characters *, (, or ). The delimiter at the beginning of the
>   string (() is why you get the empty first token. There's no way around
>   that; you just have to check for an empty first token and ignore it.
>
> The second empty token is between the first space and the ( that
>   follows it. That one's on you, because you used * (zero or more)
>   instead of + (one or more). But fixing it isn't that simple. You want
>   to split on spaces, parens, or both, but you have to make sure there's
>   at least one character, whichever it is. This might do it:
>
> \s*[()]+\s*|\s+
>
> But you probably should allow for spaces between parens, too:
>
> \s*(?:[()]+\s*)+|\s+
>
> As a Java string literal, that would be:
>
> \s*(?:[()]+\s*)+|\s+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion will be, first remove the splitting characters from the both ends(to avoid empty string), and then do the splitting.

```
String[] tokens = str.replaceAll("^[\\s()]+|[\\s()]+$", "").split("[\\s()]+"); 
                           -- replace leading or trailing--
```

Also, I have placed your splitting characters(white space, `(` `)`) inside character class `[]`

Answer (score 3):

Your regexp is wrong, try this:

<s>String[] tokens = str.split("[\s(\)]+");</s>

```
String[] tokens = str.split("[\\s()]+"); //At least one character
```

UPDATE: I've noticed your code actually removes parentheses, so it seems you don't have to escape them between brackets ... not sure why, anyone can answer that?

NEW UPDATE: Thanks @AlanMoore for the explanation, as I understand parentheses within `[]` aren't needed to be escaped.

Comment: Parentheses never need to be escaped when they're inside a character class.  The inner set of square brackets isn't really significant.  Java (and *only* Java) treats it as a "nested" character class, which is unioned with the other stuff, so it's just like `[\s*()]`.  The solution was to get rid of the `*` inside the brackets and add a `+` outside them, like you did.  I misread your answer at first; if you edit it again, I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are running into is that it is creating an empty string still between delimiters and then returning it once it hits a delimiter.

You can see what I'm talking about by adding an extra ( like this:

```
String str = "(test (_bit1 (_bit2 |bit3::&92;test#4|))";
```

The output will then become:

```
0 : 
1 : test
2 : 
3 : _bit1
4 : 
5 : _bit2
6 : |bit3::&92;test#4|
```

I would recommend the following code:

```
String str = "(test (_bit1 (_bit2 |bit3::&92;test#4|))";
String[] tokensArray = str.split("[\\s[()]*]");
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
for (String token : tokensArray) {
    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        tokens.add(token);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(i + " : " + tokens.get(i));
```

What this does is remove any empty tokens from the array, since those are considered "improper" tokens.

Comment: If you're willing to write that much code, you might as well use `Matcher#find()` in a loop to match the tokens directly.

Answer (score 0):

Index 0 is the token before the first `(`.  Index 2 is the token between the space and the second `(` in your input string.

I don't think you can avoid the first one, but you can suppress the second by using

```
str.split("[\\s()]+");
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. This regex breaks the string into characters.

Comment: You want to use `+`, not `*`.  Your regex will match wherever it's applied because it doesn't have to consume any characters.